# How to validate Mobile Number with Country code followed by 10 digits

Tags: validation-rule, administration, regular-expressions

I am new to salesforce . I have MobilePhone field in Contact. I need to validate the MobilePhone Field such that it must include (+1, +91, +355) followed by 10 digits mobile number.

NOT(REGEX(MobilePhone, "\D*?(\d\D*?){10}")) - This Regex works for 10 digits.
How can I write this regex with country code using validation Rule.
Ex: +19878767657 , +919878787678

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[+][0-9]{1,3}[0-9]{10}`

---

`[+]` to check '+' at start

`[1-9]{1,3}` to check up to 3 digits for Country code

`[0-9]{10}` to check 10 digits for Phone Number

---

Comment: NOT(REGEX(MobilePhone, "[+][0-9]{1,3}[0-9]{10}")) This regex is working